# Eval User JS Syntax On Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, try-catch, eval

I need some help trying to figure out why this is not working.

What I am trying to do is evaluate user input JS syntax using "eval()" and alerting to the user if there is an error in the JS code.

When the user clicks the "Evaluate" button the JQuery event is fired and it alerts to the user, but the problem is when they click "Evaluate" again there is no error.

HTML:

```
<label>Example Editor (Ace editor actually used)</label>
<textarea id="editor" rows="5" class="form-control"></textarea>
<button id="evaluate" class="btn btn-success">Evaluate JS</button>
<button id="set_valid" class="btn btn-warning">Set Valid JS</button>
<button id="set_invalid" class="btn btn-danger">Set Invalid JS</button>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {

        var editor = $("#editor");

        $("#evaluate").on("click", function () {
            //Evaluate JS
            try {
                eval(editor.val());
            } catch (e) {
                alert("There is an error in your JS syntax.");
                alert("Click Evaluate JS button again.. does not catch error");
            }
        });

        //Just to set valid js value
        $("#set_valid").on("click", function () {
            editor.val("$(function(){ \ralert('Valid JS Evaluated.');\r});");
        });

        //Just to set invalid js value
        $("#set_invalid").on("click", function () {
            editor.val("$(function(){\r undeclaredVariable \r\r\r});");
        });
    });
```

I have set up a fiddle here to explain in more detail:

https://jsfiddle.net/4vg3d9ka/2/

Hope someone can explain this to me :-)

PS: For the eval security issues, that doesn't matter as it is a NW.js desktop application I am building..

Thanks
Carl

Comment: Works for me in Chrome for Linux. Invalid JS is always cought, but then if I change to valid, it still goes to the catch block...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it fires only once is because the `jQuery` syntax

```
$(function(){})
```

means fire the function when the `Document` is ready, which will only trigger once. So the next time when you `eval` that code, `Document` is ready and it won't fire the callback.

If you make you invalid js to be something like `x=y`, it fires everytime.

Comment: Ahh, don't know why I didn't catch that! Thanks!

Comment: How would I ensure that the $(function(){}) function calls are always called if the user enters that as syntax?

Comment: Don't think it is possible. The `ready` event unbinds after it has been called. You could potentially parse out the function body and only evaluate that instead of the entire user input. You could also potentially reload the page when an error has occurred but then you need to save user input first. Either way, it's going to be a hack job